# Adding Tab Bar Controller to Root View of UISplitViewController?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

How would I set a UITabBarController with all its individual view controllers as the root view in a split view? IB doesn't seem to let me change the class of the root view controller to anything else…I'm using Xcode 4.

Comment: have you tried setting this programmatically in the appdelegate? I don't have my mac here, so I can't write a full answer right now :\

Comment: Hmmm…building a tab bar programmatically would be a pain. And I'm not quite sure how…

Comment: UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller1, controll2, etc, nil]; is a start ;) I'll check in when I get to work (giggles) tomorrow!

Comment: Tried putting this line in the app delegate:


 self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UITabBarController alloc] init], self.detailViewController, nil];

Leads to some strange results in portrait (which still displays a table view), then I get another table view when going back to landscape…it gets weird. 

Surely there must be a more elegant solution? Maybe something in IB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to dh14-sl and lecou—the solution was a combination of both your answers. I was trying to drag a tab bar controller from the library onto the list of elements but it wasn't working—turns out I had to drag it to the view itself. Then I had to change the parent class of my rootvc and re-setup connections, but now it seems to work! Thanks guys!

Comment: how did you re-setup the connections? by dragging to the view do you mean to drag it to the MainWindow?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the split-view based application-option? In that case, it worked for me to just extend : UITabBarController in the RootViewController.h-file. I'm not sure what behaviour you want here, but if you set it up like that, you should get the tabbar with all your views (you have to add them in RootViewController.m ofc) in the "root"-option on the navigation bar.

If you want the DetailView to show the same, you have to add a navigationcontroller to the detailview as well.

As for the "more elegant" solution with IB, I'm afraid I'm not very fond of or very experienced with IB.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add tabbarcontroller to your split view at rootview side and its very simple.
create as many viewcontrollers subclasses with xib for ipad as u want to put in tabbarcontroller.

- Then expand your splitview , u have two things  navigationcontroller(which in turns contain rootview controller),detailview controller(right side view).
- Open your library just drag  tabbar controller  exectly onto navigationcontroller ,so it will replace all that navigation controller and rootviewcontroller(i assume u dont need that rootview controller or u can create it later).
- now expand this tabbar controller u can see viewcontroller 1 - viewcontroller 2 etc.
- Now simply select  view controller 1 , open attributes and select nib file on [command 1 attribute] and select controller file for that nib file by press[command 4 attribute].
- Reapet this for  view controller 2 in tabbarcontroller and save  close IB.
  run program select landscape then u can see its done.

Comment: U can even add the more classes to the tabbar just open library and drag viewcontroller  exectly  onto the tababrcontroller u created earlier and when u expand tabbar it will show viewcotroller+tabbaritem  then just open attributes of viewcontroller select nib n cotroller file , save close IB.